# Interference between Bootstrap-Switch & Uniform js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, uniform, bootstrap-switch

I'm using [Metronic](http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/templates/admin2/) template. When I use [Bootstrap-Switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) the checkbox input is still visible on success portion as shown in image. So I discover, that happen because of using [UniformJS](https://github.com/pixelmatrix/uniform). As both want to shape inputs, some interfere happens.

[image: bootstrap-switch and uniform js]

A way to prevent that is defining css class with `display: none !important;`.
Another way is using js `not` function when initializing `uniform`. But because initialization is done by `Metronic`, I prefer not to changing that.

**Question:** Is there any better known way to remove this interfere between these tow component?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem using jquery:

```
$.uniform.restore("selector");
```

Where selector is a jquery selector string to directly select your checkbox input (not parent divs or span or ...)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Here is how I solved it using CoffeeScript:

```
$('.switch_checkbox').bootstrapSwitch()
$(document).on 'ready', ->
  $.uniform.restore('.switch_checkbox')
```